# What is the sequence of view controller methods called when a row is touched in a Swift 3 app on IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

Basically have been studying and building basic IOS apps since 2013. I am generally comfortable with Objective C and Swift 3...

The problem is that, aside from both of those languages having their quirky "issues", building IOS apps involves way too much GUI wrangling and hassling with the vague ridiculousnesses of the seemingly arbitrary decisions about what view controller methods are called when selecting a row in Master detail app. Especially ridiculous is that it's now seeming as inconsistent as Swift syntax and simply seems foolish to invest any effort making apps on a platform that is a moving target...especially when the target is already awkward to aim at when it is sitting in one place.

So...main issue today...where did "didSelectRowAt" or whatever its current Swift title is today go in the Master Detail template in XCode and what has it been replaced with???

Basically simply trying to figure out what the sequence of methods are when a touch event is registered to select a row on the table view. Essentially hoping that, by knowing the sequence of methods that will run, then I can actually start using them to build useful apps...instead of hassling with IOS GUI ridiculousness.

PS: I love Unity so much. Really hope a stripped down 2D edition of it will be made for 2D apps. So straight forward. Right now Apple is not making Me think "different"...aside from thinking of a different IDE...it's making Me think: "What is the XCode team doing at Apple and why oh why?"

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please rephrase with an easily understandable question.

Comment: You will get better help if you rewrite this rant into a more concise, clearly defined question without all of the needless commentary and opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So...main issue today...where did "didSelectRowAt" or whatever its
>   current Swift title is today go in the Master Detail template in XCode
>   and what has it been replaced with???

The Master Detail template is using segues.  In that case you don't need the `didSelectRowAt` method.

If you want to find it, just type `didSelectRow` inside of the `MasterViewController` and choose the first thing that *autocomplete* suggests.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    <#code#>
}
```

> what the sequence of methods are when a touch event is registered to
>   select a row on the table view

The template is using segues to transition to the `DetailViewController`.  The segues are wired in the Storyboard.  Your opportunity to transfer data is in:

```
prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
```

Note: The template shows the correct use of methods for displaying a detail view when using Storyboard segues.  The `didSelectRowAt` method causes confusion because it actually runs after `prepare(for:sender:)` and you can get the selected `indexPath` inside of `prepare(for:sender:)` with the `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` call.

> So, is `didSelectRowAt` still useful?

Sure, if you aren't using segues.  In that case, inside of `didSelectRowAt` you'd instantiate the `DetailViewController` yourself, configure it, and then push it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about that! Sadly still seems like such a vague and convoluted way to assemble the Master Detail style GUI. If possible, could clarify why there are multiple TableView methods and where they are called from?

Comment: TableViews are complicated but elegantly designed. The are highly customizable, flexible, and provide a good example of code reuse. I would suggest that you Google for UITableView beginner overviews and tutorials. For instance, this one: http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners/. I have answered your original question. Please accept my answer by clicking on the gray checkmark to turn it green. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. I am generally comfortable with the basics of using Table Views...yet the IOS templates included with XCode still look like spaghetti code. Honestly seems ridiculous for such a wealthy company to be so sloppy. Truly wish that apple would put some good designers on the software architecture team. Would still like to know why the multiple tableView methods aren't all combined together. Happen to know why?

Comment: I have no knowledge of Apple's design choices.  Although the APIs are a little obtuse, they do demonstrate some solid OOP design patterns and principles and provide a lot of flexibility in design without requiring a lot of code. Some of their design choices were guided by the capabilities and limitations of Objective-C.  They aren't afraid to change things, so Swift and the various macOS and iOS APIs are likely to evolve into the future.

Comment: I know now that the main issue was that I was referring to the newer split view MD app template. Much more complex. Still haven't built a copy from scratch that functions properly without using the didselectrowat method.